# Windows Hello PIN does not appear

Tags: windows-10, security, windows-hello

Trying to reset the Windows Hello PIN for my mom on her laptop. Every web page is suggesting going to `Settings > Accounts > Sign-in Options > Windows Hello PIN > I forgot my PIN`, but this option does not appear.

[image: Windows Hello Pin not appearing]

Why is this section not appearing, and how do I reset/change the PIN? Using Windows 10 (19041.630).

Comment: Is a Microsoft Account being used?  Go to Microsoft Live Sign In using a browser. Have the user log in and verify credentials. Then restart the computer, log in with the Microsoft Account and try again.

Comment: On the Lock screen, can you see 'I forgot my PIN' option? For your reference:https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-reset-forgotten-pin-in-windows-10.html

Comment: Ah, that's it! Can you knock that up as the answer and I will accept. Am still curious (and confused!) to know why the PIN section is missing in Settings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from @Candy, look for the `I forget my PIN` option on the Lock screen.

Do not now why this section does not appear in `Settings > Accounts > Sign-in Options`.